# Error with API routing with Sequelize and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing, sequelize.js

I'm having a problem tracking down why my routing is failing. I am new to Sequelize and Express routing.

Goal - 
When accessing an API endpoint '/v1/agent/:id', I want to return a JSON response from a Sequelize query. I've already confirmed the query works and brings back one row mapped to my `Agent` model.

When I launch the app, I get a `Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));` exception from Node. The exception is coming from the initializeDb function, but I don't know why.

Here's the root index.js:

```
import http from 'http';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import sequelize from 'sequelize';
import config from './config';
import routes from './routes';

let app = express();
app.server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit:config.bodyLimit
}));

app.use('/v1', routes);

app.server.listen(config.port);

console.log('API listening on port ' + app.server.address().port);

export default app;
```

My index.js file from /routes:

```
  import express from 'express';
    import config from '../config';
    import initializeDb from '../db';
    import agent from '../controller/agent'
    // handle db configs
    let router = express();

    initializeDb(db => {

      router.use('/agent', agent({config, db}));

    });

    export default router;
```

My controller for the agent model:

```
import sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { Router } from 'express';
import Agent from '../model/agent';


export default({config, db}) => {
  let api = Router();

  //query for the agent
  api.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
    sequelize
      .query(
        "SELECT agentnum AS agentno,fname,lname,agentname AS full_name,[status] FROM my_table WHERE agentnum='" + req.params.id + "'", {model:Agent})
        .then(function(agent) {
          console.log(agent);
          res.json(agent);
        });
  });
}
```

and finally, the model agents.js

```
import sequelize from '../db';

let agent = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
   sequelize.define('agent', {
      agentnum: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      fname : DataTypes.STRING,
      lname : DataTypes.STRING,
      fullname : DataTypes.STRING,
      status : DataTypes.STRING

  }, {
      tableName: 'Base',
      schema: 'Master',
      freezeTableName: true,
      timestamps: false
  });


};


module.exports = agent;
```

Anyone willing to put a second set of eyes on this please?

Comment: I've recreated the error. and the problem seems to be with the invocation of the middleware in routes.js. Take a look at how you use the routes middleware in index.js. Still working on a solution, but this might help?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that when you excecute the function in the setup it returns undefined, and that breaks the chain.. just a thought

Comment: Youre on to something. My sequelize query works when I invoke it from db.js but its getting lost when I try to reference it from initializeDb (the import statement)

Comment: from what I can see on my end is, 1: you cant invoke a function that is used as middleware. and 2: I cant seem to get the correct function to trigger when I do a get: ../:id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the api object from agent.js so that express.use is working properly in routes.js.

This has nothing to do with Sequelize so I've stripped it out from the example I got working. Have a look.

**routes.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import agent from './agent';

// handle db configs
let app = express();

app.use('/agent', agent('config','database'));

export default app;
```

**agent.js**

```
import {Router} from 'express';

export default(config, db) => {

  let api = Router();

  api.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('config', config);
    console.log('db', db);
    res.send('GET');
  });

  api.post('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('config', config);
    console.log('db', db);
    res.send('POST');
  });

  return api;
};
```

The console logs are just ment so you can see the values passed down.

Comment: YES. Face palming. Sequelize still is failing but at least the route is right. Thank you!